# Battery icon on pc

Tags: gnome-shell, battery, system-settings

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a battery icon and battery settings but I am on a computer, without battery.

Where can I configure that correctly ?

top panel:
[image]

settings:
[image]

Comment: can you share a link 0f the screenshot plZ..

Comment: It may be a mouse battery.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have made some screenshots. You see that the mouse battery is listed in periphericals.